# Function $f$ is defined on positive integers, with $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$. If $f(40)=20$ and $f(10)=14$, the what is the value of $f(500)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

UKMT Hardest Question (2015)

> Function is defined on set of positive integers is such that
> $$f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$$
> Given that $f(40) = 20$, $f(10) = 14$, what is the value of $f(500)$?

Comment: What have tried? $14=f(10)=f(2)+f(5), 20=f(40)=3f(2)+f(5)$, hence $f(2)=3, f(5)=11$ and then $f(500)=2f(2)+3f(5)=?$.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like these always rely on some decompositon of the known numbers. Just like @Feng has pointed out, try writing 500 as a product with suitable numbers (prime decompisition always helps). Now you have $$500 = 125  \cdot 4 = 5^3  \cdot 2^2$$

Now you can use that for any positive integer n it holds:

$$f(n\cdot x) = f(\sum_{i=1}^n x) = \sum_{i=1}^n f(x) $$

Now try decomposing the values the given values like Feng has suggested and you're done.